# How To Set table value to true when admin presses submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a commenting system on my website and want to add an admin signature to comments made by an admin. Not all comments are left by users as a comment is made by using a forum by anyone who visits the site, even regular users and admin users.

A user is considered an admin if the value of the `admin` boolean is `true` on the users table.

**Comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
  default_scope {order(created_at: :asc)}
  attribute :nickname, :captcha  => true
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 300 }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 30 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_commentable

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :email, :name, :admin_comment)
    end

    def find_commentable
      @commentable = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id]) if params[:comment_id]
      @commentable = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]
    end
end
```

**How comments are left on a post:** (Another form is rendered for replying to comments using `<%= simple_form_for([comment, Comment.new]) do |f| %>` instead.)

```
<%= simple_form_for([@post, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.input :body, :as => :text, input_html: { maxlength: 300 }, label: false, placeholder: "What are your thoughts?", class: "form-control", wrapper_html: { id: 'contactTextarea' } %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "Name (required) - Just your first name is okay too!", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.input :email, label: false, placeholder: "Email Address (required) - This is not displayed with the comment", class: "form-control" %>
  <div class="form-group hidden">
    <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => "leave this field blank!", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post Comment", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

**What I've tried (in the `find_commentable` method):**

```
@commentable = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
```

and

```
@commentable = User.friendly.find(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
```

while in the User model, I made the relationship of `has_many :comments, as: :commentable`

Comment: what is 'commentable' meant to represent? What fields does it have?

Comment: It sounds like the complication here is that you want to set a flag on a comment based on the user who submits it, but you don't actually have anything tying your comment and user together after the creation event. 

Do you have a way to get the current user during creation? You can set the flag then. If not, you're likely going to need to revisit your models.

Comment: @Bricky Well, it's a polymorphic relationship. A comment will belong to a post, and in some cases, it may belong to another comment as a reply. A comment is made by using a form, which is not user-specific as anyone can visit the site and fill out the form to make a comment.

Comment: @Bricky I added what I tried to do to link these together (that didn't work) and I also tried to use the code from the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model looks incomplete to me, here's what you may want to do:

- Commentable can be a polymorphic relationship for the models/entities on which a user can comment on. So, if user can comment on Post, then it can have `has_many :comments, as: :commentable`. Similarly, if the users can reply to other people's comment then comment model can also have this polymorphic relationship.
- If you want to track which user has added the comment, then ideally it needs to be a `has_many :comments` relationship in the User model. You can not use polymorphic here, because it would imply that you are trying to add comments on the User, instead of tracking which user added a particular comment on a Post or replied to any Comment.
- If you don't want to track which user posted the comment, and just want to track if it was admin or not, then you can modify the code in your controller to something like:

  ```
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :email, :name).merge(admin_comment: current_user.admin)
  end
  ```

Comment: So, to track which user commented and track if it was an admin or not, I would just use the code you provided + `has_many :comments` in the User model and `belongs_to :user` in the comments model?

Comment: I have tried your code but it didn't work. To clear things up, will the polymorphic relationship work along side your solution?

Comment: can you post your updated code in the comment or in a gist and link it here?
After adding the relationships, you would also need to set the user id in your controller, so something like:
`def comment_params`
  `params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :email, :name).merge(user_id: current_user.id)``end`

Comment: Sure, https://gist.github.com/Morganja95/3a655cf8d30ab187b62c859527df73f6 The thing is it will allow me to submit a comment when I'm not checking for an admin, but when I start to call the .merge, it simply throws up the error message I wrote via the `create` methods `else` error flash. Do you mean I need to replace the code from your answer with that, or is this for the user controller? Thanks.

Comment: @Jake the `admin_comment` attribute was if you didn't want to track the `user_id`. With the `user_id` added to the comment model, the `comment_params` method should have: `params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :email, :name).merge(user_id: current_user.id)`.
Once the `user_id` is saved in comments table, you can define a method `admin_comment` in your Comment model as: `user.admin`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get how I'm supposed to turn a comment's `admin_comment` value to true if the user is an admin with all of this. I migrated `user_id` to the comments table, made this method in the comment model: `def admin_comment
    user.admin
  end` and used this in my `comment_params`: `params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :email, :name).merge(user_id: current_user.id)` It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you verify that the `user_id` is being saved in the comments table with these changes?
When you say it is not working, are you saying that the view file that you posted on gist, returns false in this line? `if comment.admin_comment == true`

Comment: I just get a `NoMethodError in Posts#show undefined method 'admin' for nil:NilClass` highlighting `def admin_comment
    self.admin_comment = true if user.admin
  end` Is there something I'm missing? I'm no pro with ruby by any means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181292/discussion-between-jake-and-chirag).

Answer (score 1):

> I was just wondering if the admin_comment could be made true
>   automatically when an admin makes the comment instead of having to use
>   a checkbox at all.

Remove checkbox and set `before_create` in the comment model and check if the owner of comment is admin. For example:

`app/models/comment.rb`

```
class Comment < AR
  belongs_to :user

  before_create do
    self.admin_comment = true if user.admin?
  end
end
```

**BTW** your code has a vulnerable, anyone can sent the `admin_comment` parameter with `true` value.

Comment: Oh, the comments on my website actually don't normally belong to `:user` anyone can make a comment after providing credentials. Instead, it `belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true` I'll update my question with more info

Comment: It's no matter, you can refer commentable record.

Comment: How would I go about doing it that way? I've tried adding `@commentable = User.friendly.find(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]` into the `find_commentable` method and put `has_many :comments, as: :commentable` in the User model.

Comment: I've tried your answer in a few different ways but it's not letting me submit comments now. Any idea what would be the matter?